# Document creation libraries and formats?

Tags: pdf, opendocument

I am going to start my final project for spring semester at school and looking at feasibility before I put my leg in it. One of my potential projects requires me to make an archiveable document of web sessions. These archives should be searchable (and if possible with pretty design). PDF and Open Document formats are in mind for now. Is there any thing else I can look into besides these ? I want to make sure that I pick the right plan before my school starts so that I can be confident about it. I have to use C#.NET for this.

```
      Any suggestions are welcome.
```

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert logs into PDF, You can use Third Party Libraries. There are plenty of c# .NET VCL are present. Like,

- [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp)(Not free for Commercial use)
- Report.NET(free,No Support)
- [PdfSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/)(free,No Support Yet)
- [Gnostice PDFOne .NET](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_dot_Net.asp)(Non Free,With full help,support)

But if you want to create PDF using c# yourself, it is a pretty hard work since PDF uses PostScript which may be very new and complex to you. First Study the format you are going to use and make sure you can implement it. I would suggest to stick with PDF since its platform,editor independent.

http://www.gnupdf.org/Category:PDF

Comment: Gnostice eDocEngine is for Delphi/C++Builder platforms. Gnostice PDFOne .NET would be the one for the job.